# Angular JWT: Authorization Header is null?

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

Following this [tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/22/angular-8-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial) I wanted to implemenmt a login feature in my Angular app which communicates with a backend made in Spring Boot and Spring security is used in the backend.

The problem is obvious: Somehwere in my program the authorization header is not added properly

[image: Error message in the console]

In my jwt.interceptor.ts I've included a few conole.log commands to see where the problem is:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    console.log(currentUser);
    console.log(request.headers);
    if (currentUser) {
      // token exists on user so we take the request and add an Authorization header with the jwt token so we keep access
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}` //basically what I do in postman to get access
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

And when I check out the console, strangely instance currentUser seems to have a jwt-token for its body but when I try to print out its token field (which is defined in its class) that field is undefined

[image: Console printouts]

And while the there is an Authorization header appended to the request, the Bearer value is undefined

[image]

What happens in my authorization service (authorization.service.ts) is an object with key currentUser is called from the local storage and its value is returned. This is stored when we log in - we take a user from the /authenticate endpoint JSON.stringify it and store it in the local stroage. THen when getting currentUserValue I get the .value field of it:

```
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))); // user from json
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

.......

public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }
```

How do I make it so the token is added properly to my Authorization header?

I found a not-so-pretty solution to this:

In auhentication.service do this in the constructor (and add the field to the class too):

```
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.tokenString = new BehaviorSubject<any>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))).value.jwt;
  }
```

then call access that field when setting the authorization header. At least that solves this problem. If there's any better solution I'd like to know.

Here's a better solution to this problem:

First add a string field called jwt to your user class then do this in the constructor because currentUser can only be called once:

```
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.tokenString = this.currentUserSubject.value.jwt;
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
in console token available in `jwt` key and you are accessing using `token` key

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    console.log(currentUser);
    console.log(request.headers);
    if (currentUser) {
      // token exists on user so we take the request and add an Authorization header with the jwt token so we keep access
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.jwt}` //basically what I do in postman to get access
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work because my user class doesnt have a field named jwt.

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) the key for the headers is not `setHeaders` but `headers`, so this is the correct way for cloning the request:

```
request = request.clone({
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
  })
});
```

Comment: It actually works both ways the problem was that currentUser did not have any value for field token. I found an ugly workaround for it which seems to work.